# stripe api for supported settlement currencies via country code

Tags: stripe-payments

In stripe is there any api . i want to get the supported currencies for a country link this https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#supported-settlement i want to implement it on my platform account verification process so when user select the country supported currencies will be shown to below select box 
here is my countries select box code

```
<div class="form-group m-form__group row">
                                                    <label for="country" class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-form-label">
                                                        Country <span class="required">*</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-xs-12">
                                                        <select name="account-country"
                                                                class="form-control account input-lg"
                                                                id="account-country" data-stripe="country">
                                                            <option value="US">United States</option>
                                                            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
                                                            <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                                                            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
                                                            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
                                                            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
                                                            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
                                                            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
                                                            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
                                                            <option value="FR">France</option>
                                                            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
                                                            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
                                                            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
                                                            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                                                            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
                                                            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
                                                            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
                                                            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
                                                            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
                                                            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
                                                            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
                                                            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
                                                            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
                                                            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
                                                            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Country Specs API provides a [`supported_bank_account_currencies`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/country_specs/object#country_spec_object-supported_bank_account_currencies) property which has exactly this information.

e.g.

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_xxxx"
);

let specs = await stripe.countrySpecs.retrieve("DK")
specs.supported_bank_account_currencies;
```

That returns data like this : (this is just an excerpt):

```
eur: ["AT", "BE", "CH", "DE", "DK", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "IE", …]
gbp: ["GB"]
nok: ["NO"]
```

Which is:

- a list of currencies that are supported for bank account payouts in
  that country
- for each currency, the countries in which a bank    account for that
  currency can be located.

Comment: yes i but i want list of format https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#formats these ones

Comment: I don't that's available from the API right now unfortunately :(

Comment: so how we will create routing number for countries

Comment: i want to add bank account and we need to create routing numbers which is different for each country

Comment: don't that's available from the API right now unfortunately yes but tell me in which api i can get  stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#formats results of each country

Comment: As I said, I don't think there's an API, so you would need to adapt the information on that page into the logic of your application.

Comment: can i have you skype id want to ask some question about stripe actually i want to add bank account of user from my platform so i need to create routing number and it's format is different for each country so i want to know the best method to do this